# Why is the first access of the DOM slower

Tags: javascript

I noticed the first time I touch any part of the DOM via any method e.g. `.getElementById(), .querySelector(), etc` is much slower (at least an order of magnitude) than subsequent calls to the DOM. I've noticed this effect with Chrome and Safari but not Firefox. Is this the result of browser-specific optimizations, or is my understanding of Dom access or timings wildly misguided?

For example:

```js
let query

console.time("1")
query = document.querySelector("#element1");
console.timeEnd("1") // 1: 0.080ms

console.time("2")
query = document.querySelector("#element2")
console.timeEnd("2") // 2: 0.025ms

console.time("3")
query = document.querySelector("#element3")
console.timeEnd("3") // 3: 0.025ms
```

```html
<div id="element1"></div>
<div id="element2"></div>
<div id="element3"></div>
```

I totally understand that this is probably a trivial difference in the grand scheme. I'm just curious and looking to increase my understanding of how browsers handle accessing the DOM.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: must be your browser, I see no difference in Firefox, and far less difference in Chrome, nowhere near an order of magnitude - scratch that, Firefox has spectre mitigation enabled so the timings are deliberately inaccurate

Comment: A quick look into Webkit's source code tells me that there's a cache of all elements with `id` which gets destroyed when the execution ends. So _I'm guessing_ it's constructing the cache each time you run the code. Just guessing. Interesting question. But in practice, does it really matter? There are other important performance concerns to take into consideration. This is _slower_ but it's not slow at all.